# Open Custom Action Ribbon Button in a New Tab

Tags: 2013, ribbon, custom-actions

I have a few custom actions running on both the edit and new forms of a specific list in SharePoint 2013 Standard.

I'd like these custom actions, which are a link to a web url, to open in a new tab or window when clicked, rather than navigate away from the current page I am looking at. Is this possible to do?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ben,

You can do it simply by calling JavaScript in CommandAction.. and in JavaScript, try this:

```
var win = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
if(win){
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
}else{
    //Broswer has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this site');
}
```

Refer to the following if you don't know how to call JavaScript in Ribbon Action:

[CommandUIHandler Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458385(v=office.14).aspx)

[How to add a ribbon item using CustomAction in sharepoint 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011196/how-to-add-a-ribbon-item-using-customaction-in-sharepoint-2010)

[Reference a javascript script in a ribbon custom action xml](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30914/reference-a-javascript-script-in-a-ribbon-custom-action-xml)